# Best GUI Builder for Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface-builder

Any good *recent* (Java 6+) Swing GUI builders the SO community would like to recommend?  Some features I'm interested in:

- Open source - great if its open but not hard requirement
- Null layout managers - allow me to drag-n-drop controls where I want them
- Custom controls
- Design/Code split view or the ability to toggle back and forth

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Try out NetBeans - I hear it's good.  I don't do much Swing UI development, so I'm not an authority.

Comment: *Don't use null layout* - the resulting GUI's won't properly resize or work on different size/resolution monitors.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "good ..Swing GUI builders" don't use "Null layout managers".  This question has no (correct) answer.

Answer (score 23):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) is the best there is for Swing and will cover everything you need:

- free,
- open source,
- null layout available, if you **must** use it... :-) ,
- drag-n-drop,
- custom controls you can drag-n-drop too,
- great flexibility with files and projects and
- refactoring.

They offer the best integration of Matisse Swing builder.

It is absolutely stable, expandable and fast. 
There is a large number of plugins.

Hibernate reverse engineering is well implemented and there is a vast number of step-by-step [tutorials](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/matisse.html) that will help you start.

Comment: @The name of the editor would be nice: Matisse.

Comment: Trust more developers that know about art.

Comment: Quite often, netbeans can be a shore, but it's GUI Builder is easy to use, fast to build, very visual and as long as you know how to take advantage of it, it can really help you making desktop applications. For web, perhaps, is best to ask for help and/or do it yourself the html. It really pays off. If you need help, see things like 960 grid and tableless layouts.

Answer (score 17):

I personally use `WindowBuilder Pro`  by Google. It is a plugin for Eclipse and it is free.

The next release of Eclipse - Indigo - will be on the 2nd of July and it will include WindowBuilder by default.

> WindowBuilder is a powerful and easy
>   to use bi-directional Java GUI
>   designer that makes it very easy to
>   create Java GUI applications without
>   spending a lot of time writing code to
>   display simple forms. With
>   WindowBuilder you can create
>   complicated windows in minutes. Use
>   the visual designer and Java code will
>   be generated for you. You can easily
>   add controls using drag-and-drop, add
>   event handlers to your controls,
>   change various properties of controls
>   using a property editor,
>   internationalize your app and much
>   more.

Reference link: [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)

Comment: +1 It seems very similar to GWT-Designer, which is a great GUI tool.

Answer (score 12):

I personally prefer to do everything by hand, it's more precise and avoid to get some generated code that is often ugly and dependant on a specific IDE.

Comment: I agree with you, but only during the learning phase. After you get the big idea behind layouts and component adding and action listeners, using a GUI builder will reduce the programming times dramatically and will allow you to focus on the important stuff.

Comment: I agree with you and believe that it's better to develop your own library of reusable code rather than depend on GUI builders. It only takes one corrupted form file (if not using SVN or similar utility) to drive you crazy.

Comment: I felt this way for a long time. But lately Visual Studio and XCode have shown me pretty satisfying GUI generation. By hand is nice, but not spending vast time fighting out GUI details is also very satisfying.

Answer (score 6):

NetBeans GUI builder is fine. You just need to save generated XML documents with GUI data, because it's not easy to edit the generated source code manually.